# Is a tenant legally required to report the rent payments in cash to the IRS?

Tags: united-states, rent

I've been renting a room in a house in California, USA for a few years. Each month, I pay an advance payment to the homeowner. The rent is currently $650/month, and he wants cash. Legally speaking, am I required to report those cash payments to the IRS? And, does the IRS have a webpage that has instructions  or regulations regarding these cash transactions?

Comment: Does the landlord give you a receipt for those payments?

Comment: There's a requirement to file a 1099-MISC when a *business* pays rent, except when the property owner is a corporation, but I've never heard of any such requirement for a residential tenant.  I don't think the method of payment makes a difference, either.

Comment: @NateEldredge How does the type of entity the owner is affect anything the tenet needs to do?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: It says so in the [1099-MISC instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099msc.pdf), on page 2 under Exceptions.  "Payments for which a Form 1099-MISC is not required include all of the following: Generally, payments to a corporation."  I think the theory is that a corporation will have robust accounting procedures that would make it more difficult for it to conceal its income.  There is another exception if the rent is paid to a property manager or real estate agent, instead of to the owner directly.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical There's a receipt. We both agree that I write the receipt, and sign my name, he will sign his. And then, I take a photo of the receipt, and send it to him via text message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a person who pays for goods and services with cash is not obligated to report the payments to the IRS (thus simplifying your trip to the hardware store, purchases from a vending machine, etc.). There are laws requiring reporting of *receipt* of cash [31 USC 5313](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/5313) which applies to banks, which are regulated, but Ordinary Joe is not subject to this law. Receipt of over $10,000 in one or more related transactions, in the course of business, must be reported under [26 USC 6050I](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6050I). The IRS also says "File Form [MISC-1099](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1099-misc) for each person to whom you have paid during the year" if you pay at least $600 in rents, prizes awards, "other income payments", medical and health care payments and so on. Later, they [list exceptions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099msc) including payments for merchandise, telegrams, telephone, freight, storage, and similar items; payments of rent to real estate agents or property managers. The [instruction book](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099msc.pdf) then says, even more specifically,

> Report on Form 1099-MISC only when payments are made in the course of
> your trade or business. Personal payments are not reportable.

And then they repeat the exception for merchandise: but you're not paying to a real estate agent or a property manager, so *that* exception is not relevant (but the fact that the payer reports only in case it is a business covers your situation).